# Issue in adding the product to cart

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules

The problem is when I try to add a non-veg item to the cart, it is not adding. But when i come back and add other products like fish, fruits etc to the cart and again go back and add that non-veg item, it is adding. And when added to the cart, the price is displaying as 0.00.
Can anyone please help me why the non-veg item is not adding to the cart first time and the price issue ?????

Comment: Please add more details to the question, like Magento version, displayed error or code you have tried. It will be helpful to understand your issue better.

Comment: Try to debug , by disabling one by one your third party extension , and when you find extension causing error , then check the cart related customization, As per above description , this will definitely give you lead to move forward.